# Node-RED Websocket CORS policy problematic

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-red

I have created Websocket node on which flow and try to access from the Angular application. But occurs cross origin error.

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:1880/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8KkFKN: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404

- Node-RED version: v0.18.2
- Node.js version : v8.9.4

Locally installed node-red's setting is made;

```
httpNodeCors: {
       origin: "*",
           methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
       },
```

how can i resolve that?

Comment: Which version of the settings.js file did you edit? It needs to be the one listed as Node-RED starts

Comment: I didn't ask what software version of software, I asked which settings.js file you edited

Comment: @hardillb this is same, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/node-red/master/settings.js

Comment: You've miss understood, where on your system is the file you edited? There are 2 copies. 1) in the install director 2) in the user directory (normally ~/.node-red/). Only the second is used

Comment: Yes i know. When i launch on console the node-red already appear settings file and the file had changed. I'm checking for another setting file(!)

Comment: It still did not work!